# How to downsample a 1d array numpy array exponentially

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 1-d numpy array which I would like to down sample with a exponential distribution.  Currently, I am using signal.resample(y,downsize) for a uniform re-sample.  Not sure if there is a quick way to do this but exponentially

[image]

```
from scipy import signal

# uniform resample example
x = np.arange(100)    
y = np.sin(x)
linear_resample = signal.resample(y,15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(73)


# a random array of integers of length 100
arr_test = np.random.randint(300, size=100)
print(arr_test)

# lets divide 0 to 100 in exponential fashion
ls = np.logspace(0.00001, 2, num=100, endpoint=False, base=10.0).astype(np.int32)
print(ls)
# sample the array
arr_samp = arr_test[ls]
print(arr_samp)
```

I have use log base 10. You can change to natural if you want.